# It is possible to install microsoft app installer using the command line?

Tags: windows, automation

I reinstall windows all day on client pcs.

Right now I am using as script to download apps through winget, but it requires me to manually download the app installer every time through the GUI.

It is possible or am I stuck using the GUI?

Comment: Unclear: winget is not a GUI tool.

Comment: I meant the App installer which you have to install before you get access to winget in win 10.

Comment: winget is already installed on Windows 10 & 11.

Comment: In my installations it is not  available before installing the app installer.

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: ver 21h1 19043.1466

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may install `winget` using PowerShell with the following
commands:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/download/v1.1.12653/Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle -OutFile C:\PS\WinGet.msixbundle
Add-AppxPackage C:\PS\WinGet.msixbundle
```

(You may modify the path of `C:\PS` as required.)

The version `v1.1.12653` is the latest version at the moment.
The current latest and other versions can be found at the
[Releases folder](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/).

Note: The program is supposed to be installed as part of the Windows 10 21H1
version, so should already exist on your computer(s).

Answer (score 4):

This PowerShell command will download and install using the latest release available.

```
Add-AppxPackage https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/latest/download/Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
```